# Errors while Loading Most Recent Version of jQuery

Tags: php, themes, wp-enqueue-script

I am trying to set up my WordPress so that it will use the most recent version of jQuery.  Here is what I have done so far:

#### functions.php

```
<?
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'RegisterJQuery' );
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'EnqueueScripts' );

function RegisterJQuery()
{
    wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
wp_register_script( 'jquery', '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js', false, "1.9.1" );
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
}

function EnqueueScripts()
{
    wp_enqueue_script('karate', THEME_DIRECTORY . '/js/karate.js', 'jquery');
}
```

So everything in my 'karate' .js file is working as expected (including an alert that confirms that the version of jQuery has indeed been updated).  However, my theme (Elegant Theme Chameleon) uses a mouseover effect on its menu to show submenus and this effect does not work anymore.

How can I figure out what is going on?  My understanding is that if something was not compatible with the newer version of jQuery, it would still work if I upgraded the version (because of no-conflict mode).  What do you think?

William

Comment: It's probably using `hover` which I think has been deprecarted in the latest version.

Comment: Is there a good way to fix it easily?

Comment: Using the jQuery migrate plugin is the easiest way to fix it.

Comment: It will break other code too, because Google's jQuery doesn't run in `noConflict()` mode. Never replace the internal jQuery.

Comment: Google's jQuery?

Comment: Toscho meant the jQuery loaded from Google's CDN that you are using -> `//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js`

Answer (score 1):

According to [this article](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/):

> "hover" pseudo-event
>
> As of 1.9, the event name string "hover" is no longer supported as a
>   synonym for "mouseenter mouseleave". This allows applications to
>   attach and trigger a custom "hover" event. Changing existing code is a
>   simple find/replace, and the "hover" pseudo-event is also supported in
>   the jQuery Migrate plugin to simplify migration.

If you need to continue using `hover()` you may use the [Migrate plugin](http://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/#readme).

Change your function to:

```
function RegisterJQuery()
{
    wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
    wp_register_script( 'jquery', '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js', false, "1.9.1" );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
    wp_register_script( 'migrate', 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.1.1.min.js');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'migrate' );
}
```